# "to be considered " vs "should be considered"

Tags: grammar, catenative-verbs

Consider the following sentence.

> We are happy to recommended that his son to be considered for the
>   post.

This is grammatically incorrect(why?). The notes I am reading says that the correct sentence is:

> We are happy to recommended that his son should be considered for the
>   post.

Can somebody please explain why the first one is incorrect, and why the second one is correct.

**Edit:**

Does it make any difference if I simply write

> We are happy to recommend that his son should be considered for the
>   post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your first two examples have "*to recommended*". This is incorrect. You want a to-infinitive in that "We are happy..." construction (though there are alternatives), and you never have a to-initive that uses the past participle. If it happened in the past, you might use the past perfect, "we hare happy **to have recommended**", but the usual phrasing here is would be "we are happy **to recommend**". If it's not just a polite phrasing, but a description of actual emotion, it might be "we are happy **that we recommended**". However, this would more usually just be a conventional, polite way of informing someone that the recommendation can be made.

The *distinct* grammatical error in the first example is simply an extraneous *to*.

The verb *recommend* can take a verb (complete with its own objects) as an object. It is thus a *catenative* verb that takes a gerund or gerund phrase. It can also take a subjunctive construction, in which case the object is a separate verb phrase (with an optional 'that').

So, what happens after *recommend* should be a gerund phrase or, possibly after a *that*, a subjunctive verb phrase. What happens after *recommend* in your example is:

> (that) his son to be considered for the post.

That's almost a subjunctive. it just has an extraneous *to* in there. That sort of (present) subjunctive takes a bare infinitive, and should be:

> (that) his son be considered for the post.

Present subjunctives also often add in the modal *should* before the bare infinitive, which is often seen as a more modern, contemporary, accessible phrasing, hence the correctness of:

> (that) his son should be considered for the post.

Formally, both "**his son be considered**" and "**his son should be considered**" are fine, though they may convey subtle differences in meaning.

---

**N.B.**: recommend can also take a simple noun or noun phrase as object, though this can generally be interpreted as a gerund phrase whose verb has suffered ellipsis.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort. Have a good day!